# Like Box "data-height" Display Error

Tags: facebook, styles

Has there been a recent change to the functionality of the Like Box "data-height" parameter functionality?  This designation used to allow developers to set the height of the feed regardless of the usage of the other features such as "show faces."  It appears that now this parameter will only respond to allow for more faces to be shown, rather than actual postings.

My company has built a few sites that utilize this functionality, and up until last month, the widgets' "data-height" specification was working fine.  Now there is no response from this unless "show faces=true." The display of several other client webpages is now being compromised, and will require attention unless this issue can be resolved.

Is there a current work around for this?  Is this a bug? If not, is there a timetable to when the previous functionality will be restored?

Comment: You might be better off asking Facebook? I don't think anyone here would know their development timetables.

Comment: There is a bug mention about this on Facebook, but no one there has posted a legitimate response yet.  I'll update this thread with any news that I hear, and it would be really great if others would do the same.

link to the thread on FB/developers: http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/303588163096292

Comment: I received this explanation from a Facebook rep yesterday evening in regard to the inquiry posted above (as seen here: http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/303588163096292)

"Noorin Ladhani-
Hi - This is by design and has always worked like this. If you have show faces set to true, height will be updated.
Yesterday at 5:08pm · Status changed to By Design"

The change that they recently made to remove this control may be "by design," but that's not the way that this widget worked previously. There doesn't seem to be interest from the Facebook side to return height control to the developer end.

Comment: Yeah I'm facing this problem too. Worked great a few days ago, but now the plugin spills over the set height. Hope they do take the issue seriously.